# Possible to Designate a Source Port for Putty?

Tags: security, port, putty

Using Putty to SSH into a remote Linux (CentOS 7) server from a Windows 10 machine. I would like to know if it's possible to designate a port from which Putty connects to the server.

### The backstory:

The server in question has a public IPv4 address, and hence has had its SSH port changed to alleviate brute force attacks. However, I think by the virtue of me having connected from an insecure WIFI hotspot, some attacker has managed to obtain the correct SSH port - recently I have seen a great influx of brute force login attempts that weren't here before.

`cat /var/log/secure` shows that the attacker(s) come from multiple IP addresses, but they only seem to be using a handful of source ports. Therefore I would like to set up my firewall to only allow incoming SSH connections from a specific source port, in the hopes of slightly improving my security.

Comment: Clients rarely choose their source port (except DHCP clients), so probably Putty cannot do it. There are better solution to improve security: 1. Disable password based login. 2. Install [fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban).

Comment: Thanks. I will check out fail2ban as you suggested.